# Question about routing VMs with static IPs in Ubuntu (Unsolved)

Tags: networking, server, ip, routing, vmware-workstation

I have a server with an external provider that is running Ubuntu 12.04. The server is having a static IP. I have installed VMware workstation and I am running some virtual machines, one of them is for example a Windows Server 2008.

My host has provided me with a subnet of static IPs and I am trying to setup the virtual machine to have access to the internet. I have it in bridge mode in the settings of VMware.

In the IPV4 settings of the ethernet adapter of windows I am having one of the static IPs that is given to me and I have tried to setup the gateway with the gateway of the server, the static IP of the server and another ip that is mentioned as a gateway to the information of the server.

But the windows machine cannot access the internet.

I suspect there is something with the routing options of Ubuntu that I need to, but I have no idea what.

Can anyone help me with the problem. Please feel free to ask any additional information.

My provider cannot support as they do not recommend to run VMs on their servers.

Thanks for the help. The ip forwarding was deactivated so I activated it, but the problem still exists. Here is the output of the `ifconfig -a`

> ```
> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:e9:a2:7a  
>           inet adde:x.x.x.x  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
>           inet6 addr: xxxxxx Scope:Global
>           inet6 addr: xxxxxx Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:140463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:193209 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:48302672 (48.3 MB)  TX bytes:60546508 (60.5 MB)
>           Interrupt:23 Base address:0x8200 
>
> eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:e9:a2:7a  
>           inet adde:y.y.252.240  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           Interrupt:23 Base address:0x8200'
> ```

Of the `route -n`

> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0        x.x.30.1       0.0.0.0          UG    0      0        0 eth0
> x.x.252.0      x.x.30.1       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
> x.x.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0         U     1000   0        0 eth0
> x.x.30.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled ip forwarding (iirc cat 1 > /sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward)?

Also the host system needs at least one IP from the subnet you recieved. You can add another IP to an interface by creating an alias (ifconfig eth0:0 x.x.x.x netmask y.y.y.y) and the bridge needs to be able to communicate with this interface.

The subnet-ip of the host system should be the ip of the gateway for the VMs.

If that doesn't help the output of ifconfig -a and route -n with obfuscated ip addresses would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The ip forwarding was deactivated so I activated it, but the problem still exists. Here is the output of the ifconfig

Comment: The alias already exists for all the 8 addresses

Comment: Before all these I also did `route add -net x.x.252.0 net mask 255.255.255.0 gw x.x.30.1`

Comment: I think the alias idea is wrong. It is already setup in the interfaces file, but I think this way they look occupied. For example with the windows server I had an error message that there is a conflict of IP and it took another automatic IP address. When I removed the aliases I did not have the problem of the conflict and was able to ping the IP of the host and all the IPs of the subnet. But i cannot ping the gateway of the host.